# alignment in the registration form

Tags: asp.net

I have designed a form using labels and textboxes and included validation but when opening in the IE ,proper alignment was not found???what to do??

Comment: can you plz post your code over here ?

Comment: Ok thanks but the issue is solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you CSS.

Below link will help you to find solution.

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml